# Wix v4: Why is ExePackage installed outside the bundle scope?

Tags: wix, wix4

I'm trying to create a Bundle install:

```
    <Bundle Name="$(Name)"
        Manufacturer="$(Manufacturer)"
        Version="$(Version)"
        UpgradeCode="5c9ef476-24fb-4444-8ebc-3fba96f027c2">

    <BootstrapperApplication >
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
            LicenseUrl=""
            LaunchHidden="yes"
            Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
        <MsiPackage bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="1"
                    EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
                    Vital="true"
                    SourceFile="Path/to/msi/firstMsi.msi"/>

        <MsiPackage bal:DisplayInternalUICondition="1"
                    EnableFeatureSelection="yes"
                    ForcePerMachine="false"
                    SourceFile="Path/to/msi/secondMsi.msi" />

        <ExePackage Id="dotnetRuntime"
                    SourceFile="..\dotnet-runtime-8.0.2-win-x64.exe"
                    Compressed="yes"
                    PerMachine="yes"
                    DetectCondition="DOTNETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= &quot;#378389&quot;"
                    InstallArguments="/quiet /norestart"
                    UninstallArguments="/uninstall /quiet /norestart" />
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Afaik the `dotnet-runtime` is only available as `.exe` which makes it hard for me to install it with the bundle. Because, when I do, it gets installed as separate application in the ARP, which means that on the target system it will not be uninstalled along with the bundle installation.

Why is this behaviour wanted and how can I uninstall the dotnet-runtime properly when uninstalling the bundle?

Maybe interesting:
The target systems will have no connection to the internet, which makes it impossible to download a runtime published when building (as described [here](https://github.com/kurtanr/WiXInstallerExamples/tree/main/10_ASP.NET_Core6_WeatherForecastInstaller)) the installer.

I tried working around this by using `CustomActions` and packaging the installer as another Msi-Package, but all of it without any success.

As I am pretty new to wixtoolset and building installers I might overlook or not know common practices to overcome my issues. I appreciate any help.